# Solve $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (a^x + b^x - c^x)^\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to solve the limit
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (a^x + b^x - c^x)^\frac{1}{x}$$
when $a,b,c \gt 0$.
I'm looking for ways to avoid $\frac{1}{x}$ power.

Comment: I formatted your question. Please make certain I have done so faithfully. In particular, you mention "sqrt of $x$" in your question, but it did not appear in the limit you wrote down. Are you referring to the "$\frac{1}{x}$ power"?

Comment: Yes Austin that is correct thank you.

Comment: The answer (if I am not wrong) is $\frac{ab}{c}$. I'll try to punch in a solution soon.

Comment: @Nunoxic I went to my board, did the calculations and got the same. My comment'd have been the same as yours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that 
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (a^x + b^x - c^x)^\frac{1}{x}
=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\,e^{\left(\displaystyle\frac1x \log(a^x+b^x-c^x)\right)}.
$$
So we only need to calculate 
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac1x \log(a^x+b^x-c^x).
$$
Since the expression inside the log goes to $1$ as $x\to0$, we can apply L'Hôpital, to get
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac1x \log(a^x+b^x-c^x)
=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{a^x\,\log a+ b^x\,\log b-c^x\,\log c}{a^x+b^x-c^x}
=\log a+ \log b-\log c.
$$
Then
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (a^x + b^x - c^x)^\frac{1}{x}=e^{\log a+ \log b-\log c}=\frac{ab}c
$$

**Added:** as suggested by Aryabhata, it remains to justify that one can actually apply L'Hôpital. For the rule to apply, we need to have a quotient $f(x)/g(x)$, with both $f$ and $g$ differentiable at $0$, with $g'(x)\ne0$ on a neighbourhood of $0$, such that $f(0)=g(0)=0$ (less is needed, in fact, only that they go to $0$) and such that $\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)/g'(x)$ exists (it equals $ab/c$ in this case). Here $f(x)=\log(a^x+b^x-c^x)$, $g(x)=x$. The function $x\mapsto a^x+b^x-c^x$ is differentiable everywhere; for $x$ near $0$, the values of this function approximate $1$; on any neighbourhood of $1$ that doesn't contain $0$,  $\log$ is differentiable, and then so is the composition $f(x)=\log(a^x+b^x-c^x)$. And $g'(x)=1\ne0$ for all $x$.

Comment: This seems circular: LHospital assumes that the derivative exists at $0$. But the limit you are trying to find is exactly the derivative at $0$! (This is what I was hinting with my answer).

Comment: @Aryabhata: I'm using L'Hopital to find the value of the limit, not to prove that the derivative exists. The function $\log(a^x+b^x-c^x)$ is C$^\infty$ on small enough neighbourhoods of $0$.

Comment: Finding a limit also entails proving its existence (implicitly or explicitly). Otherwise, all you have done is, "if the limit exists, then it is so and so", which is incomplete.

Comment: @Aryabhata: L'Hôpital is exactly about the existence of the limit.

Comment: You missed mentioning that $g'(x) \ne 0$ in a neighbourhood of $0$, but that is fine here as $g(x) = x$. Sure, Lhopital also proves existence, but that was not my point.

Answer (score 2):

Another hint: Let $f(x) = \log (a^x + b^x - c^x)$

What is $f(0)$?

What is $f'(0)$? (The derivative at $0$).

Comment: f(0) is 0 and f(tag)(0) is minus infinity..trying to think what this tells me

Comment: @TOm: What is the definition of $f'(0)$ in terms of limits?

Comment: @Tom: Are you sure about $f'(0)$?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**:
$$
  \left( a^x + b^x - c^x \right)^\frac{1}{x} = a \left( 1 + \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^x - \left(\frac{c}{a}\right)^x \right)^\frac{1}{x} = a \left( 1 + x \cdot \frac{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^x - \left(\frac{c}{a}\right)^x}{x} \right)^\frac{1}{x}
$$
Compute $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^x - \left(\frac{c}{a}\right)^x}{x}$, then use the golden limit $\lim_{x\to 0} \left( 1 + \alpha x\right)^\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: This needs some justification. For instance consider limit of $(1+x)^{1/x}$ as $x \to 0$ (which is $e$). We just cannot replace $(1+x)$ by $1$ because $x \to 0$.

Comment: @Aryabhata Sasha is not suggesting that.

Comment: this looks like magic but yet again the limit to compute when x approaches 0 is hard for me to do

Comment: @Peter: I am pretty sure Sasha is not doing that, but people who are just learning these things might think that that is what Sasha is doing. Just pointing out the potential pitfall.

Answer (score 1):

Where you start is to realize that $1^\infty$ is an indeterminate form, so you can use L'hopital's rule after you rewrite it as,

$$e^{\left(\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln(a^x + b^x - c^x)}{x}\right)}$$

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid L'Hopital: Write $(a^x + b^x - c^x)^{1 \over x}$ as $a(1 + ({b \over a})^x - ({c \over a})^x)^{1 \over x}$, so that it suffices to find
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (1 +({b \over a})^x - ({c \over a})^x)^{1 \over x}$$
Taking logs, it's enough to find
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} {\ln(1 +({b \over a})^x - ({c \over a})^x) \over x}$$
$$=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} {\ln(1 +({b \over a})^x - ({c \over a})^x) - \ln(1 +({b \over a})^0 - ({c \over a})^0) \over x - 0}$$
This is the difference quotient for the derivative of $\ln(1 +({b \over a})^x - ({c \over a})^x)$ at $x = 0$. Using the chain rule to find this derivative and plugging in $x = 0$ gives you $\ln(b/a) - \ln(c/a) = \ln(b/c)$. Going backwards, the original limit is ${\displaystyle ae^{\ln(b/c)} = {ab \over c}}$.